# Как задать правильную ссылку для типа записи с таксономией в ACF?

Tags: wordpress

Через ACF PRO создал тип записи Услуга(services), к нему сделал таксономию Тип услуг(cat-services)
Урлы через произвольные ссылки делал(оставил пустым так и не понял что там писать), но в итоге у записи Услуга-1  ссылка   site.ru/taxonomiya-1/usluga-1, а вот у таксономии site.ru/cat-uslugi/taxonomiya-1
как сделать чтобы урл на таксономию был site.ru/taxonomiya-1   ?

урлы у записи менял через функцию которую нашел в интернете

```
function true_post_type_permalink( $permalink, $post_id, $leavename ) {
 
    $post_type_name = 'services'; // название типа записи, вы можете найти его в админке или в функции register_post_type()
    $post_type_slug = 'services'; // часть URL товаров, не всегда совпадает с названием типа записи!
    $tax_name = 'cat-uslugi'; // ну это понятно, название таксономии - категории товаров
 
    $post = get_post( $post_id ); // получаем объект поста по его ID
 
    if ( strpos( $permalink, $post_type_slug ) === FALSE || $post->post_type != $post_type_name ) // не делаем никаких изменений, если тип записи не соответствует или если URL не содержит ярлык tovar
        return $permalink;
 
        $termini = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $tax_name ); // получаем все категории, к которым принадлежит данный товар
 
 
        if ( !is_wp_error( $termini ) && !empty( $termini ) && is_object( $termini[0] ) ) // и делаем перезапись ссылки, только, если товар находится хотя бы в одной категории, иначе возвращаем ссылку по умолчанию
            $permalink = str_replace( $post_type_slug, $termini[0]->slug, $permalink );
 
    return $permalink;
}
 
 
add_filter('request', 'true_post_type_request', 1, 1 );
 
function true_post_type_request( $query ){
    global $wpdb; // нам немного придётся поработать с БД
 
    $post_type_name = 'services'; // указываем тут название типа записей товара
    $tax_name = 'cat-uslugi'; // а также название таксономии - категории товаров
 
    $yarlik = $query['attachment']; // после того, как мы изменили ссылки товаров в предыдущей функции, WordPress начал принимать их за страницы вложений
 
    // а теперь давайте получим ID товара, ярлык которого соответствует запросу на странице
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var(
        "
        SELECT ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_name = '$yarlik'
        AND post_type = '$post_type_name'
        "
    );
 
    $termini = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $tax_name ); // товар должен находиться в категории (одной или нескольких)
 
 
    if( isset( $yarlik ) && $post_id && !is_wp_error( $termini ) && !empty( $termini ) ) : // изменяем запрос, если всё ок
 
        unset( $query['attachment'] );
        $query[$post_type_name] = $yarlik;
        $query['post_type'] = $post_type_name;
        $query['name'] = $yarlik;
 
    endif;
 
    return $query; // возвращаем результат
}
```

Comment: А как у Вас реализован контроллер? обычно это все через него делается

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman я всё через плагин ACF PRO сделал, в функции записал только вот код который выше

Comment: Я не силен в wordpress-е так что сперва хотел бы узнать что у вас отвечает за контроль перехода от одной страницы к другой?

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman это вопрос исключительно по ВП, не пут(г)ай ТСа контроллерами и пр чистым пхп.

Comment: Во первых выкинь это всё что "нашел в интернете". Во вторых внимательно изучи https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/woocommerce-kill-performance и оставь свою дурацкую идею. В третьих никогда не ставь метку `php` когда вопрос касается ВП.

Comment: @SeVlad  прошу прощения удалил тег php. Ну если говорят прям надо, то как быть? я всего лишь простой работяга)

Comment: Как быть - забить на идею извращения с урлами. При создании кастомных сущностей вообще ничего этого не трогать, всё оставить по дефолту. Ну и учить матчасть разумеется.

Comment: @SeVlad да нет конечно, есть миллион сайтов и нормально живут с такими урлами, это же не сайт ИМ где 100к + позиций и категорий, а просто тип отдельный тип записи и категории, там урлов от силы 30 наберется в общем

Comment: Попробуй всё же осилить по ссылке.